# Как получить диапазоны ID из базы?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mariadb

Есть база данных MySQL, в ней таблица с полями ID (AUTO_INCREMENT), key, val.
Она имеет следующи вид

```
1            house    Oslo
2            house    Perth
...
483   inn        country
484   inn        Georgetown
485   inn        country view
...
123886   inn        cozy inn Brighto
123887   inn        cozy inn janesvill
123888   inn        cozy inn
123889   inn        cranbury inn nj
...
179314    travel    travel agent
179315    travel    what is the safest way to travel
179316    travel    when is the best time to travel to Italy
...
224317 resort Mexico
224318 resort Miami
224319 resort Wyndham
```

Ключи в таблицу добавлялись пачками, т.е. добавили 1000 кееев с ключем inn, затем добавили 5000 кеев с ключём resort и т.д.

Нужно написать функцию на PHP, которая принимает key, например inn и которая бы прошлась по таблице и выдала для кея inn массив диапазонов ID, т.е. для кея inn она должна выдать

```
[
    0 => [ 'min' => 483, 'max' => 485 ],
    1 => [ 'min' => 123886, 'max' => 123889 ]
]
```

Подскажите, как лучше всего написать такую функцию?

Установлена MariaDB 10.5.8

Comment: Подскажите, а что пробовали, что конкретно не получалось?

Comment: делаем запрос который выбирает id для всех записей с inn отсортированный order by id. Цикл php его перебирающий, в конце итерации запоминаем в переменной текущий id, на следующей итерации в начале цикла в этой переменной значение из предыдущей строки. Сравниваем текущее и предыдущие значения, если отличаются более чем на 1 и в выходном массиве есть данные, пишем предыдущий id в последнюю строку в max, добавляем новую строку с min=текущий id. по завершении цикла добавляем ставим значение последнего id в max

Comment: Или реализуем аналогичную логику на переменных в самом mysql. Если mysql >=8.0 то же самое на оконных функциях

Comment: @Mike select min(id), max(id) from table where inn=:inn?

Comment: Это типичный gaps and islands. Делать это на стороне PHP - глупо, такую обработку данных следует выполнять на стороне СУБД. Укажите ТОЧНУЮ версию SQL-сервера.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Нет, там же inn не одним блоком идут, надо группы выделить

Comment: Установлена MariaDB 10.5.8